# Being penalized on Page Speed by Google Fonts

Tags: google-pagespeed

I'm using a font that is in Google Fonts on my site and I'm importing through css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900');
```

The problem is that the [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) notifies the following information:

**Make sure the text is still visible when you load webfont**

Use the CSS font view feature to ensure that text can be viewed by the user while webfonts are loaded.

Below the notification, all font specifications I'm importing are listed:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Has anyone had this problem?

Do you know how this can be adjusted?

I'm having this notification on multiple sites that use Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `font-display: swap;` or `font-display: fallback;` under `@font-face`

Google Front URL for with `font-display: swap;`:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900&display=swap
```

Google Front URL for with `font-display: fallback;`:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,800,900&display=fallback
```